# how to import upsell products magento 2?

Tags: magento2

> Actually i am trying to import upsell products magento 2? is there any
>   way to import upsell products.

[image]

> But this way it is not working in magento 2
>
> below is the solutions for it

[image]

Comment: i got the solutions for

Comment: if you have got the solution, you can post it as an answer, so that other may get the benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way it's worked for magento 2.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Create Your Related Product Linker Import File.**

Follow the formatting in the Image below.

[image]

[Click here to download sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wH3Xwhjgyi1ekLgr9KkJ2F1BEFKRJbpnAMYV4Rwl31c/pub?output=csv)

**Columns**

[image]

I hope it works!

Comment: No this way it's not working for Magento 2

Comment: This is the one that worked for me, for some reason I could not import the positions, first attempt and reading this topic led me to try several times, then I deleted the position columns and imported fine. Noted Magento no longer appears to have "position" on the back end for related products admin side but for the project I'm on this was no problem. I just imported the three columns with the item sku's to update the products:
_links_related_sku
_links_crosssell_sku
_links_upsell_sku